# How do I configure my 2 RAID drives so I can use it as /home?

Tags: partitioning, raid

I've installed Ubuntu 11 64-bit to a 2 TB drive. It is on `/dev/sda` - port 1 of SATA Host Adaptor. This contains `/dev/sda1` (1 MB boot), `/dev/sda2` (2TB EXT4), `/dev/sda3` 8.6GB SWAP.

I also have:

- `/dev/sdb`   2TB RAID COMPONENT
- `/dev/sdc`   2TB RAID COMPONENT

which also show as

- `/dev/dm-0`  not partitioned
- `/dev/dm-2`  not partitioned which is mounted as `/media/RAID_HOME`

I'm completely stumped as to how to use this version of Ubuntu to make these drives seem as just one raid mirrored drive and then how to transfer `/home` onto it.

Answer (score 1):

When you install, choose manual partitioning, select the raid array, and set it to be mounted at /home.